# Get best values sum or alone from object in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Hi guys i have the problem with getting best value from object that I get from SQL query.
From my SQL query i get random number of answers with different values ,but they are ordered from smallest to biggest number. And I have other value and I must see where will the best match for the values from the object equal or bigger that other object.

Here is an example:
user number is 15;
and from my sql query numbers are 2 6 6 8;

so my function must do this checks:

```
number of check|nubmers|sum|check
1.1             2       2   x
1.2             6       6   x
1.3             6       6   x
1.4             8       8   x
2.1.1           26      8   x
2.1.2           26      8   x
2.1.3           28      10  x
2.2.1           66      12  x
2.2.2           68      14  x
2.3.1           68      14  x
3.1.1.1         266     14  x
3.1.1.2         268     16  ANSWER 16>=15
```

I hope you understand what I want to do.
If you have some idea please write it down.
Thank you.

Comment: show the query so that the ordering can be achieved prior to fetching

Comment: and how to do that ? I use MySQL